# so afraid vs very afraid, and about the ambiguous of 'so afraid' sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

> 1.She was so afraid that she(herself) couldn't have any meal all the day.
>
> 2.She was so afraid that she(herself) didn't have any meal all the day.
>
> 3.She was very afraid that she(not herself) didn't have any meal all the day.

Q1)There is a difference in meaning between the three sentences?

Q2)Could the 1 and 2 sentences be read in two ways? as in 
the 1 seems to mean either 'she feared that she(herself) couldn't have any meal all the day' or 'she feared such an extent that she(herself) couldn't have any meal all the day.'

and also, the 2 seems to mean either 'she feared that she(herself) didn't have any meal all the day' or 'she feared such an extent that she(herself) didn't have any meal all the day'.

Answer (score 3):

Your first two sentences are a bit clumsy. The third sentence is not grammatical.

What you appear to be trying to compare is statements such as:

> She was so afraid that she **couldn't** eat.

with

> She was so afraid that she **didn't** eat.

The second statement is clear. Her fear was such that it discouraged/prevented her from eating.

This is also the more obvious meaning of the first statement.

It's possible - but most unlikely - to construe the first statement to mean:

> She was so/very afraid that she might not be able to eat.

Plainly, this means something quite different, that she feared that she might not be able to take food.

However, there is very little chance of ambiguity.